# How to fully hide this element at the top?

Tags: ublock-origin

I have a very small monitor. on  [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/), I want to hide the top element at all times.

I have tried the following:

```
regex101.com##.Gceny:style(display:none !important;)
```

But this just takes it from how it originally was:
[image]

to:

[image]

There is now just a blank space, where the element used to be.

If I try obtain the name of this blank element, the element picker ends up selecting the whole page.

How can I hide this blank space or element as well?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the source where you are applying this to?

Comment: @GeneMoody-Action1 hey, what do you mean by source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other elements have a specified `top: 50px` and so you are hiding the header content, but there is no reflow.

Try targeting the `div` with `id="regex-app"` (which is the whole container) by setting its `position` to `fixed` and its `top` to `-50px`

Not tested for side-effects.